# Cannot load data from FireBase into Recycler view

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a list of Recycler View by loading data from FireBase
[image]

For that I made MainList.java

```
public class MainList {
private String imageResourceId;
private String name;

public MainList() {}


public MainList(String imageResourceId, String name){
    this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImageResourceId() { return imageResourceId; }

public String getName(){ return name;}
```

}

and MainListAdapter

```
public class MainListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainListAdapter.MainListViewHolder>{

ImageView item_image;

List<MainList> mMainList;
LayoutInflater inflater;

class MainListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView item_name;
    ImageView item_image;

    MainListAdapter mAdapter;

    public MainListViewHolder(View itemView, MainListAdapter adapter) {
        super(itemView);

        item_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        item_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        this.mAdapter = adapter;
    }
}

public MainListAdapter(Context context, List<MainList> main_list){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mMainList = main_list;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MainListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View mItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new MainListViewHolder(mItemView, this);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainListViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MainList mainList = mMainList.get(position);
    holder.item_name.setText(mainList.getName());
    Picasso.get().load(mainList.getImageResourceId()).into(item_image);
    //holder.item_image.setImageResource(mainList.getImageResourceId());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMainList.size();
}
```

} 
*And I try to use  use Picasso inside of OnBindViewHolder for my image*

and in MainActivity I try to get my data from FireBase **to fill** my List

```
main_comics_List = new ArrayList<>();

    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ComicsData").child("AllComicses");
    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                MainList item_of = dataSnapshot1.getValue(MainList.class);
                main_comics_List.add(item_of);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

But when I start my app ***nothing shows at the place of my Recycler*** and I get ***the message***

[image]

What am I doing wrong? And how do I solve it? 
I would appreciate you answering me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance variables inside the class `MainList` should be the same as the attributes inside the database. Therefore inside the `MainList` add the following:

```
private String imageLink;
private String title;
```

And the setters and getters:

```
public String getImageLink() { return imageLink; }

public String getTitle(){ return title;}

public void setImageLink(String imageLink) { this.imageLink = imageLink; }

public void setTitle(String title){ this.title = title;}
```

Also in your database it doesnt seem that you are using `name` and `imageResourceId` therefore you can remove them from the class `MainList`.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. I have just tried adding setters (and getters) as you said but now I get this message:                                                                                         
    No setter/field for Title found on class com.example.comicsreader.MainList (fields/setters are case sensitive!)
    No setter/field for ImageLink found on class com.example.comicsreader.MainList (fields/setters are case sensitive!)

Comment: in your database the attributes should be `title` and `imageLink` with lowercase `t` and lowercase `i`

Comment: Peter, I changed database attributes. But the matter now is that my list shows up only when I rotate my device... (If I start landsape nothing shows, but when I rotate device reycler is loading as it should be). I am so confused. What kind of magic is it?  (In my app I login by FireBase and then I go to my activity with the recycler. Maybe that  affects somehow. I am truly lost)

Comment: Yes. I am using this: mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070247/recycler-view-shows-data-in-portraint-but-not-in-landscape-even-i-set-it-again-a it's probably something in ur layout missing

Comment: Did you check ur layout?

Comment: Sorry for a long respond there was night in my country. Yes I checked my layouts of item and of layout that contains Recycler, nothing seems wrong. I am going to try to remake the layouts and see what happens.

Comment: Finally! List was not loading after the first launching of Activity because it did not have the essential line "mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();"  (Inside of onDataChange and onCancelled) now it is working just fine. Thanks for your help Peter!